# How to transpose array of object in javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to transpose values from 2 objects to 3 objects.In first object I want 1st value from each objects etc.
If 2 objects with 3 values then after transpose it will become 3 objects with two values.
before transpose
data is

```
obj 0:
0:"17"
1:0.052708692712917476                                                              
2:0.05170448850051073
3:0.036428533456315845

obj 1:
0:"16"
1:0.039474102915939856
2:0.04788765943666215
3:0.03651675504080556
```

After transpose I want following obj

```
obj 0: 
        0:0.052708692712917476    //1st value of 17 i.e obj 0
        1:0.039474102915939856     //1st value of 16 i.e obj 1

obj 1:
        0:0.05170448850051073     //2nd value of 17 i.e obj 0
        1:0.04788765943666215     //2nd value of 16 i.e obj 1

obj 2:
        0:0.036428533456315845
        1:0.03651675504080556
```

Comment: please add the data in [literal syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer), and what you have tried, of course.

Comment: `0:{0.036428533456315845}` what is this mean, it doesn't seems valid as an Object

Comment: Those look more like arrays and not objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could transpose by getting the values and skipping the first property of the inner objects.

```js
var data = { 0: { 0: "17", 1: 0.052708692712917476, 2: 0.05170448850051073, 3: 0.036428533456315845 }, 1: { 0: "16", 1: 0.039474102915939856, 2: 0.04788765943666215, 3: 0.03651675504080556 } },
    result = Object.values(data).reduce(
        (r, a, i) => (Object.values(a).slice(1).forEach((v, j) => (r[j] = r[j] || {})[i] = v), r),
        {}
    );

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

ES5

```js
var data = { 0: { 0: "17", 1: 0.052708692712917476, 2: 0.05170448850051073, 3: 0.036428533456315845 }, 1: { 0: "16", 1: 0.039474102915939856, 2: 0.04788765943666215, 3: 0.03651675504080556 } },
    result = {};

Object.keys(data).forEach(function (k, i) {
    Object.keys(data[k]).slice(1).forEach(function (l, j) {
        result[j] = result[j] || {};
        result[j][i] = data[k][l];
   });
});

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: how can I do this for dynamic objects and its properties?Thanks for rply

Comment: Sure, this is a fancy solution. But lets forget about browser support, im not sure if arrow functions are widely supported.

Comment: what means dynamic? just more or less properties, or do you mean the skipping part?

Comment: e.g I have 17 objects and each having 25 properties.I want 25 object with 17 properties.

Comment: @Nick, you could use just normal function and polyfills for the rest.

Comment: @Ashish, you could try it.

Answer (score 0):

With only 2 objects and 2 properties?

Really easy, by accessing their properties directly!

```
var object1 = {
  p11: v11
  p12: v12,
  p13: v13
}

var object2 = {
  p21: v21
  p22: v22,
  p23: v23
}
```

You can use 2 notations: dot and array. And you are gonna need an additional helper variable so you don't step over property in 1 object before you transfer it to other.

**Dot notation:**

```
var helper = null;

helper = object1.v1
object1.v1 = object2.v2;
object2.v2 = helper;
```

**Array-like or brackets notation:**
var helper = null;

```
helper = object1.v1
object1["v1"] = object2.["v2"];
object2.["v2"] = helper;
```

It's hard to read what exactly transformation you wanna since but this is a basic simple way to let's say exchange properties of 2 objects. You can rinse and repeat this principle for multiple exchanges.

Remember, don't write new value over old one before you put old value in an object somewhere.

Oh, now that you made a proper example in question I see what you need. You need to chunk down 2 big objects of coordinates into smaller chunks each having a property from one. I wouldn't call that transpose, at least not by mathematical definition of it.

You need a function actually to give it 2 objects and it returns an array of small objects (ones with 2 properties). I hope those are object literals because unless you can number the properties by name (you have 1, 2, 3 and so on) in JS there is no way to ensure order of properties in object. Arrays are special objects used for that.

Oke, assuming you posted literals (only in inpropper syntax) let's write a function:

```
var getCoordinates = function (obA, obB){
   var o1 = null;
   var o2 = null;
   var coordinatesArray = [];
   // determine which object under property 0 has bigger value to know order

   if (obA[0] < obB[0]) {
     o1 = obA;
     o2 = obB;
   }
   else {
     o2 = obA;
     o1 = obB;
   }


  // get value pairs assuming both objects have same number of properties
  // if not, get as much as you can until one object runs out of coordinates
  for (i=1; true; i++;){ // start at 1, 0 is reserved for object order
      if (o1.hasOwnProperty(i+"") && o2.hasOwnProperty(i+""){
        var coordinatePair = {};
        coordinatePair["0"] = o2.[i+""];
        coordinatePair["1"] = o1.[i+""];
        coordinatesArray.push(coordinatePair);
      } 
      else break;
  }

  return coordinatesArray;
  }
}
```

Written purely from the head so I might have missed syntax (I am on tablet). But it should demo you the right idea.

Comment: I want transpose for more than 20 objects and and each having more than 25 properties.Thanks

Comment: Try this idea, it's written as simple as possible, you can take shortcuts here and there.